# how to copy values through rows in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2016

[image: Image of cells]

How can I transfer left 2 columns from 1-9 and 10-18 to fill in the right table skipping a row
dynamically for a big amount of data

Answer (score 2):

Using and INDEX and some math inside an IF:

```
=IF(ISODD(ROW($ZZ1)),INDEX($A$1:$B$9,INT((ROW($ZZ1)-1)/4)+1,INT(MOD(ROW($ZZ1)-1,4)/2)+1),"")
```

Change the `$A$1:$B$9` to your reference, then put it in the first cell of the output and drag/copy down.

[image]